# Copy a file and rename based upon SQL query using PowerShell?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I need to move around 12000 documents from one directory to another using PowerShell, however, I also need to rename each document based upon a SQL query which strips out any spaces, removes the file extension etc.

I've written the SQL for it (as shown below), but I'm not sure how/if it's possible to do the above using PS?

```
'Author' + CAST(AuthorId as varchar)  + '_' + REPLACE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(originalFilename), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(originalFilename)) + 1, 999)), ' ','')
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you provide examples how the original file name looks like and the desired output?

Comment: It'll be:
Original filename = 'anyoldte xtblahblah.pdf'
New filename = 'Author321212_0003anyoldtextblahblah'

The SQL statement is fine, I'm just not sure how to implement the the move and rename from sql server using powershell

Comment: There is a `Move-Item` and `Rename-Item` cmdlet to do that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not sure how to get it to connect to SQL server to fetch the original filename, calculate the new filename and then rename.

Comment: You need to start with something like `Invoke-SQLCmd` to query what you need. Then you can manipulate the local files. Look up that cmd first.